# code splitting doesn't work as I expected in async import

Tags: webpack

```
import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "EmojiPicker" */
    /* webpackMode: "lazy-once" */
    /* webpackPreload: true */
    "./EmojiPicker"
).then(module=>console.log(module))
```

I tried to use async import in my `webpack` project.
Finally, I found there are two additional bundles:

[image]

However, what I want is an additional single bundle which combines `vender~EmojiPicker` and `EmojiPick`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are many configuration options for code splitting under the `optimization.splitChunks` settings: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#configuration

I haven't tested, but you may be running into the default `cacheGroups` config. Try disabling it:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        default: false
      }
    }
  }
};
```